# How can I convert the date string calculated by CoreData to ISO format YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS +000?

Tags: cocoa, core-data

I have a string like this, 
285298171.84336197376251220703

and I know it's created by CoreData and I want to find a way to convert it into ISO format, can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Added: actually this is in an XML file which an application created.
285298171.84336197376251220703
281021264.12619298696517944336

Answer (score 1):

Without more context, it's impossible to be sure, but you're almost certainly observing a string-ified `NSTimeInterval` (a `typedef`'d `double`) that represents the number of seconds since a reference date. You want the uderlying `NSDate` that it represents which you can convert to any standard string format via `NSDateFormatter`.